# Tips on getting best GPU performance while using PNG Texture Atlas?

Tags: swift, xcode, optimization, sprite-kit, png

Hello I'm a new developer, I have a spider solitaire app on the App Store. When I profile my app's GPU usage the profiler tells me that its usage is "very high." I've tried to cobble a solution together by researching, off and on, for months on the internet, but haven't found it yet.

The spider solitaire variant of solitaire uses 104 cards which could potentially be on the scene at the same time and they are all PNGs. I'm pretty sure, from researching, that the pngs are the reason for the performance hit.

The reason I want to use PNGs over less resource intensive file formats is to replicate the rounded corners of a playing card. I've tried using shape masks but that just made performance worse. Other than that, I have seen reference to "tiling" on SO, but haven't been able to parse that information.

I've sized the card images correctly. I'm getting 99%, or so, 60fps in my game, but of course, I am concerned about the energy consumption. I should mention that the game is 2D SpriteKit.

Is this just a "suck it up, you made a design decision that is costly" type situation? Or is there a better way? Is caching a thing, weak references maybe? Please, be nice, I'm not very experienced with this, but I love it.

Thank you very much to anyone who can provide any resources!

Comment: How complicated are the PNGs? If they're simple enough, you might get better performance (from less graphics memory needed to be filled/used) by using vector graphics instead

Comment: Interesting! Pretty simple, standard playing cards and then some color cards. I’m not sure why I didn’t think to explore some other file formats. I guess that’s why you ask others! Thanks.

Comment: When you turn on `showsDrawCount` for the view, what does it show?  A high draw count (more than, e.g., 5 or 10, or the number of layers in a stack of cards) might indicate something simple like not having the textures in an atlas or accidentally having `ignoresSiblingOrder` set to `false`.  If the scene is mostly static as well, you might try wrapping the mostly-static stuff inside an `SKEffectNode` and having `shouldRasterize` set to `true`, so it'll cache the static part of the scene as one flat graphic when possible.

Comment: So helpful, thank you very much!